# "Errors were encountered while processing: steam:i386" and "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, steam

Deleted Steam from terminal, now, when I try to install or remove anything I get the same error:

```
tim@tim-X55A:~$ sudo apt-get remove gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data libamd2.4.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libblas-common libblas3 libcamd2.4.1
  libccolamd2.9.1 libcholmod3.0.6 libgegl-0.3-0 libgfortran3 libgimp2.0
  liblapack3 libmng2 libraw15 libsdl1.2debian libumfpack5.7.1 python-cairo
  python-gobject-2 python-gtk2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gimp
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/875 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16,0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 193119 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gimp (2.8.16-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package steam:i386 (--configure):
 package steam:i386 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Post the entire command and output

Comment: run `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat ` and try again

Comment: nope, not working :(

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install --reinstall steam:i386 && sudo apt -f install`